# Are keyword arguments useful only to increase flexibility over order of arguments?

Tags: python, arguments

Arguments in Python are of two types: Keyword arguments and positional arguments.

Consider the following definition of a **square_1_sum** function. It takes two numbers $a, b$ as input and returns the number $a^2 + b$

```
def square_1_sum(operand_1, operand_2):
  sum_result = operand_1 ** 2 + operand_2
  return sum_result
```

The result of calling function using keyword arguments gives flexibility over order of arguments

```
square_1_sum(operand_2 = 3, operand_1 = 4)
square_1_sum(operand_1 = 4, operand_2 = 3)
```

gives the same result of **19**.

If we use the positional arguments, they will give different results

```
square_1_sum(3, 4)
```

gives **13**

```
square_1_sum(4, 3)
```

gives **19**

so, I am guessing that the **only purpose** of introducing keyword arguments is to increase flexibility in passing arguments to a function remembering the keywords.

Am I true? Are there *any other uses* for keyword arguments (compared to positional arguments in which the position of an operand is important)?

Comment: They're more useful for optional arguments.

Comment: I think the brevity of positional arguments are the main "pro" of using them. One advantage you might not be aware of: You can unpack a dictionary and use the key-value pairs as keyword arguments, s.t. `square_1_sum(**kwdict)` with `kwdict={operand_1=4, operand_2=3}`.

Answer (score 2):

They're much more useful for optional arguments.

```
def my_print(value, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False):
```

The keywords allow you to provide only the options you need. If you call the function with positional arguments, you need to supply all the intermediate arguments.

And the real `print()` takes a variable number of positional parameters. You have to use keyword arguments so it knows where the end of the positional arguments are.